# Rails image not loading in Nginx passenger server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline

I have installed Nginx Passenger to deploy my rails application. I have done everything perfectly and my sites is running in server with CSS and Java-script, but i am not able to see any images in the server. All my images are located in the /app/assets/images/

**Production.rb**

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  #config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  #config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://10.200.101.227'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "pyraMID_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  ENV["APPLICATION_URL"] = "http://ip_address"
  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enable/default**

```
    server {
  listen 80;
  #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

  server_name ip_address;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env    production;
  root         /var/www/test-site/public;

  location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    root /var/www/test-site/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header  Cache-Control public;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use live compiling of asset instead of do this `config.assets.compile = true`.

Comment: @AjayBarot I changed config.assets.compile = true but still images is not loading. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what the error which am getting in console - 4-1600x1000.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: You have to add `config.assets.digest = true` in `production.rb`. And I am assuming that you are doing assets clean and pro compiled again to see the results.

Comment: @AjayBarot i tried as you said but still the image is not loading :-(

Answer (score 3):

please try this in your .conf file

```
location ~ ^public/assets/ {
 add_header Last-Modified "";
 gzip_static on;
 expires 1M;
 access_log off;
 add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

keep location as `^public/assets/`, i have face the same problem before

Answer (score 1):

By default public assets are false in rails.

There are two ways:

1. Change following line from false to true in `production.rb` as following

   `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`
2. If you have `.env` or `.env.production` file then write the following in same

   `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES = true`

   restart the server.

Comment: Do i need to change anything from the setup side?

Comment: Need to change in production.rb only

Comment: I have updated my production.rb and Nginx /sites-enables/default file, please look for it and give your feedback and also please let know if you need any further assistance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A fix that worked for me was to clear the cache

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

Thanks you all for your response.